# Conditional Expectation of Tourist Arrival Time

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

A lost tourist arrives at a point with 3 roads. The road brings the tourist back to the same point after 1 hour of walk. The second road brings the tourist back to the same point after 6 hours of travel. The last road leads to the city after 2 hours of walk.

Assuming that the tourist chooses a road equally likely at all times and does not remember the past choices. What is the expected time until the tourist arrives to the city?
Hint: use the law of total expectation to write an equation of the expected time.

My Attempt:
I can assume that time must be at least 2 hours and $P[X=2] = 1/3$

By the hint I can write down:
$E[X] = E[X|X=2]P[X=2] + E[X|X>2]P[X>2]$

But that's as far as I can go. I tried to calculate from the conditional expectation but I just can't think of a way to calculate it as I need the pmf.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please read up on the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathjax to format your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Don't partition on the time it takes to walk to the city, rather, partition on the *next road taken*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A lost tourist arrives at a point with 3 roads. The road brings the tourist back to the same point after 1 hour of walk. The second road brings the tourist back to the same point after 6 hours of travel. The last road leads to the city after 2 hours of walk. Assuming that the tourist chooses a road equally likely at all times and does not remember the past choices.

Don't partition on the time it takes to walk to the city, rather, partition on the *next road taken*.

Let $\mathsf E(T)$ be the expected time taken to reach the city from the crossroad, and $\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}r)$ be the expected time *when given that the tourist takes road $r$* (which may or may not loop back to the crossroad).

Thus the Law of Total Expectation you have been hinted to use is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(T)&=\mathsf P(R{=}1)~\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}1)+\mathsf P(R{=}2)~\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}2)+\mathsf P(R{=}3)~\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}3)\\[1ex]&=\tfrac 13(\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}1)+\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}2)+\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}3))\end{align}$$

Comment: I tried figuring out the $E[T|R]$. For $E[T|R=3] = 2$, obviously. But for $E[T|R=1]$ and $E[T|R=2]$, I tried $\Sigma_{t=3 or t=8}^\infty$, but that obviously diverges....

Comment: Recursion, @SharonZhong . If you take the first road you travel 1 hour then return to the crossroad. $$\mathsf E(T\mid R{=}1)=1+\mathsf E(T)$$